# How to print all column values from excel using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an Excel sheet like this

```
Listener_name   Listener IP     Listener Service
server1         12.xx.xx.xx       java
server2         12.xx.xx.xx       java
server3         127.0.0.1        oracle
```

and I want to print all values for Listener `IP`    column.

My current Python code looks like this:

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('report-201808March0709AM522986.xlsx')

sheet = book.active

a1 = sheet['J1']
a2 = sheet['J2']
a3 = sheet['J3']

print(a1.value)
print(a2.value)
print(a3.value)
```

but it's only 3 columns of values and I have more than 200 values. Is there any way we can print all values using a loop?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Just printing values seems a bit .. simple? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('report-201808March0709AM522986.xlsx')
sheet = book['sheet name']
```

The rows of the sheet can be accessed using `sheet.rows`. To iterate over the rows in a sheet, use:

```
for row in sheet.rows:
    print row[1].value
```

As each row in rows is a list of `Cells`, use `Cell.value` to get the contents of the Cell.

**Edit:** Added output

```
Listener IP
12.xx.xx.xx
12.xx.xx.xx
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I want to print all values of particular column.

Comment: `for cell in sheet['B']` is more compact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas for this and avoid a loop.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 999

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

print(df['Listener IP'])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: You don't avoid the loop, you just conceal it in Pandas.

Comment: There's a subtle, but important, difference. The `for` loop implicit in `read_excel` isn't written in Python, it's in lower-level optimized code.